# What PHP version still supports mysql_query()?

Tags: php, mysql

We have a PHP based website that we will migrate to another web hosting (AWS). I noticed that mysql commands, e.g. `mysql_query()` are still used to execute queries. The latest PHP 5.x based version no longer supports `mysql_query()`.

What is the PHP version that we need to configure on the new web host to be able to run `mysql_query()`?

Comment: Instead of investing effort into keeping such an old code in production you should start porting it _now_. There are _very_ good reasons why that old extension has been deprecated and why more secure alternatives got promoted _for years now_.

Comment: Actually, we are already porting from the old code to the new website version. Running in a lower PHP version to support mysql_query() is a temporary short term solution. Our long term solution is to run the new website version with the ported MYSQLi commands. Thanks for the input :-)

Comment: You could try to shim it https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim

Comment: Have you tried simply replacing `mysql_` with `mysqli_`? That’s not a long term solution, of course, but you might get some relief there.

Answer (score 4):

The mysql extension was deprecated in php 5.5.0 and removed completely from php 7.0.0

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: That means PHP 5.4 should still be able to run mysql_query(). Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes you should be able to run your system on PHP 5.4.x without any issues related to the mysql module.

Answer (score 0):

None that you should be using. Any development should be done in 7.2 or a above.  5.x is no longer supported and should be considered not to be secure.

http://php.net/supported-versions.php

You need to go in and replace the outdated mysql_query with modern methods. Upgrading may also break from regex conversions depending on how you did them. PHP developers had years of notice before the old mysql_query functions were deprecated. On a positive note php 7.x is a lot faster and more secure.